# Line numbers collide with marginnotes on even pages in a book

Tags: geometry, line-numbering, marginnote

I am having a bit of a problem with margin notes colliding with line numbers on the even pages of a book. I would like to adjust the margins so that the notes can stay where they are. I think this means I need to increase the outer margin and the marginparsep on even pages.

A minimal working example is included below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\title{lineNumbersAndMarginNotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers*}

Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginpar{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

\newpage

Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginnote{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

\end{linenumbers*}

\end{document}
```

I'm mostly interested in how to affect geometry on the even-sided pages.
Thanks,

Comment: You probably do not want the margins not to match, right? That would look very strange. The outer margin should be the same on odd an even pages else a 2-page spread will be lopsided. You do, however, need a sufficiently wide `marginpar` width to accommodate the notes. This won't completely solve the problem because the notes will still overlap the line numbers, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. The `marginpar` width is smaller than it needs to be to accommodate the margin notes. This can be fixed by setting the width using `geometry`.
2. The line numbers and the notes are competing for the same territory.

There are 2 obvious solutions. One is to flip the page numbers so that they are opposite from the margin notes:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[switch*]{lineno}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=12.5ex]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\title{lineNumbersAndMarginNotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{linenumbers*}

    Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginpar{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.
    \vfill
    \newpage

    Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginnote{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

  \end{linenumbers*}

\end{document}
```

[image: flipped numbers]

This has the advantage of symmetry.

Alternatively, you can alter the alignment of the margin notes, further increasing the size of `marginpar` to accommodate the line numbers and the notes when needed:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=15ex]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\raggedleft}
```

[image: re-aligned margin notes]

I would also recommend not justifying the text inside the notes as this is not going to work well with such narrow width. Using `ragged2e` might also help.

Comment: I do not want to flip the line numbers for certain technical reasons, but increasing the `marginparsep` is an option. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can increase the `marginparsep` using `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[marginparsep=7mm]{geometry}   %% adjust 7mm at will
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[marginparsep=7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\title{lineNumbersAndMarginNotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers*}

Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginpar{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

\newpage

Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginnote{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

\end{linenumbers*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to put `\raggedright` inside the `\parbox` and adjust the `marginparwidth` too for your convenience.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=12ex,marginparsep=7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\title{lineNumbersAndMarginNotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers*}

Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginpar{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{\raggedright Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

\newpage

Here is some text that has line numbers, the text is not important, but it needs to have a few lines otherwise it won't demonstrate the issue I would like to figure out. I don't just want a plug in solution\marginnote{\fbox{\parbox{10ex}{\raggedright Here is a margin note, I think}}}, I'd really like to understand how to get the \texttt{geometry} package to act differently on odd and even pages.

\end{linenumbers*}

\end{document}
```

[image]